# Trying to Retrieve Line Status from TfL's API (JSON)

Tags: json, ajax

I'm messing around with AJAX/JSON for a bit of practice, and I'm attempting to retrieve live data from TfL's (Transport For London) API pertaining to train line statuses.

Here is a snippet of the JSON data I am working with:

```
[
{
"$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.Line, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
"id": "bakerloo",
"name": "Bakerloo",
"modeName": "tube",
"disruptions": [],
"created": "2018-10-05T11:35:58.573Z",
"modified": "2018-10-05T11:35:58.573Z",
"lineStatuses": [
{
"$type": "Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities.LineStatus, Tfl.Api.Presentation.Entities",
"id": 0,
"statusSeverity": 10,
"statusSeverityDescription": "Good Service",
"created": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
"validityPeriods": []
}
],
```

I am trying to retrieve the name of the of the line (called "name" in JSON data) and the current status (called "statusSeverityDescription" in the data"). The code below can retrieve the name, but I have no idea how to retrieve statusSeverityDescription as it appears to be held within {}'s within an array.

```
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'https://api.tfl.gov.uk/line/mode/tube/status',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(key, value){
                    var line = value.name;
                    var status = value.lineStatuses[0];
                    $("#content").append("<tr><td>" + line + "</td>" + "<td>" + status + "</td></tr>");
                });
            }
        })
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the status object, so you just need to access `status.statusSeverityDescription`.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!